# How many integers in between 1 and $10^7$ are divisible by 3, 5 or 7?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How many integers in between 1 and $10^7$ are divisible by 3, 5 or 7?

I try with that the number of integers between 1 and $10^7$, inclusive, which are relatively prime to 63:

$$(10^7)/3=3333333$$

$$(10^7)/5=2000000$$

$$(10^7)/7=1428571$$

$$(10^7)/63=158730$$
Total number of integers $= 3333333+ 2000000+ 1428571 - 158730=6603174$

Is that correct or wrong ? please help

Answer (score 3):

This problem is just *begging* to be solved with the [inclusion/exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle):

First, count how many are divisible by $3$, $5$, and $7$ individually.  Then subtract the number that are divisible by both ($3$ and $5$), ($3$ and $7$), and ($5$ and $7$).  Lastly, add back the number that are divisible by all three.

For intuition, visualize a Venn diagram:

[image]